# Why Can't I Select Dynamically (PHP) Generated Options?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, html-table

I am having an issue with a table where each cell contains an id'd input or select field.  The cell contents are dynamically generated from a MySQL query.  Everything works fine except for my dynamically generated SELECT drop downs.  I am using the following code in a switch statement:

```
case 'crew_1':
case 'crew_2': 
    echo '<td><select class="'.classExt($types[$key]).' '. $key .'_c" id="' . $key . '--' . $idx .'">';
    echo '<option value="" selected="selected"></option>';
    while ($rowtech = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rtech)){
        echo '<option value="' . $rowtech['name'] . '">' . $rowtech['name'] . '</option>';
    } mysqli_data_seek($rtech,0);
    echo '<option value="TEST">TEST</option>';      
    echo '</select></td>'; break;
```

This creates the following HTML:

```
<td>
    <select class="varchar crew_1_c" id="crew_1--1">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="Name 1">Name 1</option>
        <option value="Name 2">Name 2</option>
        <option value="TEST">TEST</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

From this I can select the blank or 'TEST' option and it returns the correct value in a console.log, but if I choose one of the dynamically generated names, the box returns back to the default blank value.  I get the same responses on Chrome and IE.

Where is my disconnect?

Included for the person requesting the script generating to output to console:

```
$('tbody select, tbody input').change(function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Looks to me like your select tag needs a name.

Comment: http://viper-7.com/oZlDVk

Answer (score 0):

OP, you're missing the `name` attribute.
This works fine for me:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <select class="varchar crew_1_c" id="crew_1:1" name="choice">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="Name 1">Name 1</option>
        <option value="Name 2">Name 2</option>
        <option value="TEST">TEST</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>

<?php
var_dump($_REQUEST);
?>
```

Comment: I included the name attribute and still get no select.  It works stand alone, just not when it's generated by the PHP 'while' statement.  I can cut that section out into a standalone form with no issues.

Comment: Does it have a form around it?

Comment: No, but that would affect the entire SELECT and not just the PHP generated part, correct?  I can select the blank and hard coded option just fine.

Comment: Nope, it needs to have a form otherwise it can't really send anything anywhere -- that IS what you're trying to do right?

Comment: I'm going to take the field value on a change and $.post it to an update query.  I won't be sending a form as a whole.  Basically creating a (partially) editable table.

Answer (score 0):

Found my issue.  The JS request earlier had me dig back through my code to discover that I was setting my values toUpperCase() for submission for consistency, but that was breaking my value match on the drop down.  I set my values to uppercase in the select options also and TA-DA!

Thanks for the help, guys.  Sometimes it takes a fresh pair of eyes to point out the obvious.